# Cypress - Logout with Firebase SDK not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js, cypress

I have an application written in `Nuxt.js v.2.14.6` and want to use `Cypress v.5.4.0` for end-to-end testing. I use `Firebase SDK v.7.21.1` for authentication. I created 2 Cypress commands, one for creating a new user and one for logging a user out.

**The setup:**

```
Cypress.Commands.add('register', ({ email, password, username }) => {
  cy.visit('')
  cy.contains('Sign Up').click()
  cy.url().should('contain', 'sign-up')

  cy.get('input[id=username]').type(username)
  cy.get('input[id=email]').type(email)
  cy.get('input[id=password]').type(password)

  cy.get('input[type=submit]').click()

  cy.contains('Creating your account...')
  cy.location('pathname', { timeout: 20000 }).should('eq', '/')
})
```

The user registration in my application is performed on the url `/sign-up` (Hence the url check in the 3rd line). On successful registration, the user is redirected to the homepage (Hence the location check in the last line).

```
Cypress.Commands.add('logout', () => {
  cy.visit('')

  cy.get('[data-cy=nav-profile-dropdown]').click()
  cy.get('[data-cy=nav-sign-out]').click()

  cy.contains('Sign In')
})
```

The user can logout via a dropdown in the navbar. The logout is successful, when the dropdown in my navbar disappears and the `Sign In` button appears (Hence the contains check in the last line).

In my application I further have a plugin `authlistener.client.js` that is using `Firebase SDK`'s method `onIdTokenChanged` to determine a `signOut` event. The `authlistener.client.js`looks like this:

```
export default async function ({ app, store, $sentry }) {
  const isServerAuthenticated = store.getters.IS_AUTHENTICATED

  if (!isServerAuthenticated) {
    try {
      await app.$fireAuth.signOut()
    } catch {}
  }
  app.$fireAuth.onIdTokenChanged(async function (authUser) {
    if (authUser) {
      try {
        await _handleAuthSuccess(authUser)
      } catch (e) {
        await _handleAuthError(e)
      }
    } else {
      await _handleSignOut()
    }
  })

  async function _handleAuthSuccess(authUser) {
    const { claims, token } = await authUser.getIdTokenResult()
    const user = BuildProfile(authUser, claims)

    await store.dispatch('SET_SESSION_COOKIE', token)
    store.commit('SET_USER', user)
  }

  async function _handleSignOut() {
    store.commit('SET_USER', null)
    await store.dispatch('SET_SESSION_COOKIE', null)
  }

  async function _handleAuthError(error) {
    $sentry.captureException(error)
  }
}
```

In the template of my navbar, I have a button where the sign out event is triggered.

```
<button @click="signOut" role="menuitem" data-cy="nav-sign-out">
 Sign out
</button>
```

The `signOut` method that is being called looks like this:

```
signOut() {
  this.$fireAuth.signOut()
  this.view.isUserMenuOpen = false
}
```

This method uses the `Firebase SDK`'s `signOut()` method that is handled by the `authlistener` plugin described above.

The process described is working fine, both in production as well as in development via `npm run dev`.

**The problem:**
Cypress is not able to perform the logout correctly. Cypress is able to create a new user with my `sign-up` page. Cypress can also open the navbar dropdown and click the sign out button. What is failing in Cypress is the actual logout of the user, that is, the user dropdown is not replaced by the sign in button.

Since Firebase is storing auth information in an `indexedDb`, I compared both the indexed db of my local dev setup and the Cypress environment. Interestingly, there were no user information stored in the Cypress environment after the user creation, but in the local dev setup there were relevant user information stored.

**Related problems/solutions**
I found a Github [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1208) that addresses some problems with Cypress in combination with Firebase indexedDb. Unfortunately the solution of clearing the indexedDB before every test run did not work for me.